# Qt connect() SLOT and "this" pointer

Tags: c++, qt, class, signals, slot

The following code works:

```
connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(myMemberFunction()));
```

---

That other doesn't:

```
connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(this->myMemberFunction()));
```

---

Why?

Comment: It compiles but looks like it doesn't accept it as valid SLOT

Comment: From where is `connect` being called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SLOT() macro writes a function that can be called (as a function pointer) to deliver the slot, it uses the argument as the name, it ISN'T itself a function call.